# How to add a JSON Object in local storage to a Fragment List on Android Studio

Tags: android, json, google-maps, listview, android-fragments

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "adak": {
    "lat": 51.883,
    "lon": -176.633,
    "wikipedia": "Adak,_Alaska",
    "city": "Adak"
  },
  "nuku%ca%bbalofa": {
    "lat": -21.133,
    "lon": -175.2,
    "wikipedia": "Nuku%CA%BBalofa",
    "city": "Nuku%CA%BBalofa"
  },
  "apia": {
    "lat": -13.833,
    "lon": -171.833,
    "wikipedia": "Apia",
    "city": "Apia"
  },
...
```

And I want to add it to a List Fragment on my project (made it with Tabs) to look like a normal Scrolling List, and also save the latitude and longitude to put markers with them on a map (the other tab).
Somebody can help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
        ArrayList<MyModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        try {
            for(int i =0 ; i<array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                data.add(new MyModel(object.getString("lat"),object.getString("lon"),
                        object.getString("wikipedia"),object.getString("city")));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Model code:

```
public class MyModel{
            private String lat;
            private String lon;
            private String wikipedia;
            private String city;

            public MyModel(String lat, String lon, String wikipedia, String city) {
                this.lat = lat;
                this.lon = lon;
                this.wikipedia = wikipedia;
                this.city = city;
            }

            public String getLat() {
                return lat;
            }

            public void setLat(String lat) {
                this.lat = lat;
            }

            public String getLon() {
                return lon;
            }

            public void setLon(String lon) {
                this.lon = lon;
            }

            public String getWikipedia() {
                return wikipedia;
            }

            public void setWikipedia(String wikipedia) {
                this.wikipedia = wikipedia;
            }

            public String getCity() {
                return city;
            }

            public void setCity(String city) {
                this.city = city;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to convert it into object class, you can use a GSON library.
try [this](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) tutorial, and you can put the object to your ListAdapter.

[Here's](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) another full tutorial that can help all your problem including put it on list `